# Continuity and partial derivatives of this function in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm having some troubles in understanding how to proceed on this exercise. The requests are: does it exist $L \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(-1, 0)$? Which partial derivatives among $f'_x(-1, 0)$ and $f'_y(-1, 0)$ do exist for all values of $L$ and why?

$$f(x, y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x^2+x}{x^2-y^2-1}, & x^2 - y^2 \neq 1 \\\\ L, & x^2-y^2 = 1\end{cases}$$

**ATTEMPTS**

The first request "seems" easy, unless I made a mess. I thought the limits must be coherent, namely equal and finite, that is:

$$\lim_{x\to -1} \left(\lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{x^2+x}{x^2-y^2-1}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0}\left(\lim_{x\to -1} \dfrac{x^2+x}{x^2-y^2-1}\right)$$

Which doesn't occur because the lhs limit evaluates to $1/2$ whereas the rhs limit evaluates to $0$.

Now my problem is to understand if the function is continuous for some values of $L$, because for the partial derivative request I thought to use the difference quotient, hence the definition of the derivative. But when I do it, the $L$ remains there.

I cannot use polar coordinates, by the way (if this makes sense to be told).

**Some work**

So going with the definition of the derivative, evaluating ad $(-1, 0)$ I get:

$$f'_x(-1, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{(-1+h)^2 - (-1+h)}{(-1+h)^2 - 1} - L}{h}$$

This turns out to be $$f'_x(-1, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left(1 - \frac{1}{h} - L\right)$$

Hence the limit is infinite and $f'_x(-1, 0)$ does not exist.

Then

$$f'_y(-1, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{-1+1}{1-h-1} - L}{h}$$

But this turns out to be infinite too...

Comment: What's the problem with $L$ remaining there? If you replaced $L$ by $13$, and the $13$ remained there, would that be cause for concern to you?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Uhm, let me try again, and I will eventually add my work to explain me better!

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Add some work. Can you tell me if it's legit or wrong?

Comment: I didn't fully go through the tedious calculations, but just looking at the function definition, it's definitely true they none of the two partial derivatives exist for *all* values of $L$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Well, it's somehow reassuring, but now I have to ask: how do you tell "just by looking at the function" ? I'm interested in learning some "trick" in this sense!

Comment: I imagine how the function looks like when plotted. A scalar function of two variables can be plotted as kind of a hillscape, where the horizontal position is determined by x and y, while the height is determined by the function. Now the function definition says that it is constant along the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$. The partial derivatives at $(-1,0)$, which is on the hyperbola, are now determined by how the function behaves on a straight line through that point. These lines only cross the hyperbola at one single point in the vicinity of $(-1,0)$ (the point being $(-1,0)$ itself)...

Comment: ... and on these straight lines, the parameter $L$ determines $f$ in just a single point, no more. But if I change a function's value in just a single point, it can't at most be differentiable (or even continuous) for a single one of the possible values, never for all of the values.